# Solaris 10- high kernel utilization (%sys)

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

Our production server shows a high %sys utilization.
This is a Solaris 10 x86 box with Oracle 10g R2 database

Configuration:
CPU - Intel Xeon 4 CPU (8 socket each)
Memory - 128GB (80GB SGA, 10GB PGA, 30GB for System)

This server shows high CPU utilization in 'sys'.
How can i determine the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris there's only *one* answer to that - `Dtrace`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Dtrace is a good option if you know how to use it.  The [DtraceToolKit](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html#DTraceToolkit) can help tremendously if you don't know how to use it.

Other programs that can help you find the culprit:

- `prstat` -> (try `prstat -amL`)
- `apptrace`
- `iostat`
- `vmstat`
- `mpstat`

And, even though it's an older book now, Adrian Cockroft's [Sun Performance Tuning: Sparc & Solaris](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131496425) is still a must have for anyone that works with Solaris, and for pure insight reasons, I would recommend it to users of any flavor of Unix/BSD/Linux.